# why does emacs sometimes prepend asterisks to org mode headings

Tags: org-mode, prelude, emacs25

When I open this file in emacs

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/limist/literate-programming-examples/master/01-clojure-literate-ants/literate-ants.org

[image: Screenshot of the org file in Emacs showing indentations]

I see emacs is showing me ** lines as *** lines.

Whats the logic behind this?

Update:
I noticed the file has a heading like this
`#+STARTUP: align indent fold nodlcheck hidestars oddeven lognotestate`

Comment: When I open this file with no custom org configuration (e.g. emacs -q), I don't see the same thing. The STARTUP line you mention is enabling org-hide-leading-stars, which means I only see one * per heading, just indented to the correct level. Have you customized org mode in some way? A theme that changes the `org-hide` face might also be a factor.

Comment: The STARTUP line also sets `oddeven`, but it looks like perhaps you are using `org-odd-levels-only`? Even then you would have to explicitly convert the file (see `org-convert-to-odd-levels`). Opening an existing file and switching to odd levels only would not actually change the file. Things I would try: Switch to text-mode, do you see 2 or 3 stars there? If 2, then look at org appearance / theme settings. If 3, then the file has been modified, possibly by `org-convert-to-odd-levels`. I'd also try starting emacs with -q and see if the behavior is different.